# Shop section of facebook pages through api/javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook introduced a shop section for facebook pages. I need to manage my page's shop section through javascript sdk but I am unable to find the propoer docs or reference to do that. I know how to manage or update simple fields of your pages through sdk with post method using FB.api:

```
FB.api(/page_id_and_post_method, function(response) {
    console.log("PAGEEEEEE DETAILS", response);
});
```

So, the problem is that I just could not find the proper field name for that 'shop' section so as to update it.

So how can I read/update the 'shop' section of my page through sdk/api just as the shopify do as we can see below:

https://www.facebook.com/Womansera/shop?ref=page_internal&rid=221671794535129&rt=9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature that Facebook is testing right now, with Shopify as a partner (and maybe a few others.)

It is not available for other 3rd-party apps yet.

Comment: Do you know if the access will be available to everone soon?

Comment: @basex: No I don't. If/when they do, they will likely announce it through the usual channels (developer blog, changelog, ...)

Comment: It's now been months and months. I wonder anyone knows when new companies can have access to it.