# Facebook Graph API - reading page shop

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to read the shop section from a facebook page?

I am trying to write an app to consume data from a facebook page.
I have seen references to a `products` field and a `product_catalogs` edge to be read in the page API reference. But calls to these in API Explorer have returned just the page ID and an empty data list respectively. Like so:

```
GET /v2.8/{page-id}?fields=products HTTP/1.1
  Host: graph.facebook.com

result: {"id": <page_id>}


GET /v2.8/{page-id}/product_catalogs HTTP/1.1
  Host: graph.facebook.com

result: {"data": []}
```

I have added multiple products to page's store. What should I be doing to access this data?

EDIT: I have seen at least [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37609898/2623364) that sugests this is not presently possible, but it's talking about the `shop` section, I am hoping alternative paths will allow access to this data.

Comment: did you try with a page token?

Comment: well.. I am using the graph explorer, using the admin acount for the page to get a user token, that should be enough, right?

Comment: no, i assume you need a page token. you should use one anyway, if you want to get stuff from pages.

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Well.. no deal. Page token also returned nothing